# How to calculate phase spectrum of autocorrelated time signal

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Appreciate some help on how to calculate the phase spectrum of a autocorrelated time signal. As input I have a time series pilot for 70 seconds sampled every 2 ms. I can calculate the auto-correlation of this signal which is symmetrical around time zero. The power spectrum looks fine (apart from scaling), but the phase spectrum lags to -200 radians. As it is symmetrical around the zero time lag, I am expecting a zero phase spectrum. Problem is I do not know how to inform the phase_spectrum that signal is symmetrical and without it I can understand the phase shift. How can I solve this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import window_none

file_name = 'pilot_signal.csv'
dt = 2/1000 # sampling interval is 2 ms
df = 1/dt # sampling frequency

pilot_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
time = pilot_df['Time']
amplitude = pilot_df['Amplitude']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 7))

ax[0].set_title('pilot')
ax[0].set_xlim(0, 30000) # first 3 seconds only
ax[0].set_ylim(-175, 175)
ax[0].plot(time, amplitude)

ax[1].set_title('autocorrelation')
max_lag = 250
corr_function = np.correlate(amplitude, amplitude, mode='full')
corr_function = corr_function[(len(amplitude)-1)-(max_lag-1):(len(amplitude)-1)+max_lag]
time_lags = np.arange(-(max_lag-1), max_lag)
ax[1].plot(time_lags, corr_function)

ax[2].set_title('magnitude')
ax[2].set_xlim(0, 100)
scale = 'linear'  #  'dB' # or 'default'
ax[2].magnitude_spectrum(corr_function, Fs=df, scale=scale, window=window_none)

ax[3].set_title('phase')
ax[3].set_xlim(0, 100)
ax[3].phase_spectrum(corr_function, Fs=df, window=window_none)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You need to shift your signal such that the first element is t = 0 and the last element is t  = -dt, e.g., 
 xc = np.concatenate((x[len(time_lags)//2:], x[len(time_lags)//2+1:][::-1]))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my own question and as suggested in the comment to get the proper phase response the correlation function first needs to be re-ordered whereby the positive half of the correlation function becomes the first half of the reordered correlation function and the negative part becomes the second half. My solution for this is:

```
cf_reordered = np.concatenate((corr_function[max_lag-1:], corr_function[0:max_lag-1]))
```

where max_lag are the samples before t=0 and after t=0 and `len(cf_reordered) = 2*max_lag - 1`

(in the program max_lag is 257)

Putting it all together the sample program now looks like below. Whereby it also checks if phase values are modulus 2*pi and maps the values between -pi and +pi. Phase is now zero phase between the range between 2 Hz and 90 Hz which is the correct sweep range as shown in the results at the bottom.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import window_none

# values of the sweep are stored in pilot_signal.csv with following parameters:
# - sweep length: 64 seconds
# - start frequency: 2 Hz
# - end frequency: 90 Hz
# - amplitude between -100 and 100

file_name = 'pilot_signal.csv'
dt = 2/1000 # sampling interval is 2 ms
df = 1/dt # sampling frequency
pi = np.pi

pilot_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
time = pilot_df['Time']
amplitude = pilot_df['Amplitude']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 7))

ax[0].set_title('pilot')
ax[0].set_xlim(0, 30000) # first 3 seconds only (expressed in ms)
ax[0].set_ylim(-150, 150)
ax[0].plot(time, amplitude)

ax[1].set_title('autocorrelation')
max_lag = 257
corr_function = np.correlate(amplitude, amplitude, mode='full') / len(amplitude)
corr_function = corr_function[(len(amplitude)-1)-(max_lag-1):(len(amplitude)-1)+max_lag]
time_lags = np.arange(-(max_lag-1), max_lag)
ax[1].plot(time_lags, corr_function)

ax[2].set_title('autocorrelation re-ordered')
cf_reordered = np.concatenate((corr_function[max_lag-1:], corr_function[0:max_lag-1]))
time_lags = np.arange(0, 2*max_lag-1)
ax[2].plot(time_lags, cf_reordered)
print(len(corr_function))
print(len(cf_reordered))

ax[3].set_title('magnitude')
ax[3].set_xlim(0, 100)
scale = 'linear'  #  'dB' # or 'default'
ax[3].magnitude_spectrum(corr_function, Fs=df, scale=scale, window=window_none)

ax[4].set_title('phase')
ax[4].set_ylim(-4, +4)
ax[4].set_xlim(0, 100)
# get the phase spectrum values and frequencies values; plot invisible and use a non default color
cf_phase_values, cf_freq, _ = ax[4].phase_spectrum(cf_reordered, Fs=df, window=window_none, visible=False, color='r')

# check for modulus 2*pi and keep values between -pi and pi
cf_phase_values = np.mod(cf_phase_values, 2*pi)
cf_phase_values[cf_phase_values>pi] -= 2*pi

ax[4].plot(cf_freq, cf_phase_values)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Results:
[image]